# Field gets radio button's item id instead of its value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have snippet:

```
<%= f.input :purpose, as: :radio_buttons, collection: category.subcategories, 
             wrapper: :vertical_collection_inline %>
```

which lines values of **category.subcategories** horizontally how I want

[image]

The problem is, when I select either of option, it assigns that option's ID, but not its value.

How should I refactor the code?

Comment: isn't it a good thing ? storing `ID` instead of value ? If not, just add `.map` on `subcategories` to only get the value

Comment: ID is already there in DB. Here I want to assign a value "Rent" to be a value for field "Purpose" of another table.

Comment: Try with `f.radio_button` instead

Answer (score 0):

Using IDs has advantages as warned in the comments, however what you’re trying to do should work with either:

```
category.subcategories.collect(:&values)
```

Where `values` is the name of the field which hols “Rent” etc.

The more railsy way to do this is with [collection_radio_buttons](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons), like this:

```
f.collection_radio_buttons(:purpose, category.subcategories, :value, :value)
```

Again where “value” is the field name.

Comment: Thanks. But still not working. `Subcategory` has only 1 field `name`. In my case, `category.subcategories`, contains 3 records with values Rent, Sell and Buy.

Comment: Specifically, I've tried this 
`<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:purpose, category.subcategories.collect, :name) %> ` and got error:
_wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 4..6)_